# How to set the FAB in a frame layout to bottom of the screen without using the set gravity option

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener

i'm trying to add a touch listener to FAB so that i can drag it any where in the FrameLayout, well my touch listener is working fine but the default position of the FAB  is coming at top of the screen , i wanted it to be at the bottom right of the screen.

if i set the gravity to bottom,my touch listener wont work, how do get it dynamically ?

below is my woking code

**Layout code**

```

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/dashboard_foreground"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/dash_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/mike"
            app:fabSize="normal" />

</FrameLayout>
```

```

**Activity**
```

```
private int mTopMargin = 300;
mFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.dash_fab);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams lpDraggableView = new 
FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

mFab.setLayoutParams(lpDraggableView);

mFab.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchToDrag);

public View.OnTouchListener OnTouchToDrag = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams dragParam = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (((int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight() + mTopMargin)) > 0) {
                    dragParam.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight() + mTopMargin);
                    TCLog.d("Custom", "topMargin" + ((int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight() + mTopMargin)));
                    dragParam.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth());
                    v.setLayoutParams(dragParam);
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                //  dragParam.height = 150;
                //  dragParam.width = 150;
                dragParam.height = v.getHeight();
                dragParam.width = v.getWidth();
                dragParam.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight() + mTopMargin);
                dragParam.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2);
                v.setLayoutParams(dragParam);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

};
```

Even i tried the seting the Layout params dynamically, it is going out of the screen.
```

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels ;
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels ; 
lpDraggableView.topMargin = dpHeight;
lpDraggableView.leftMargin = dpWIdth;
mFab.setLayoutParams(lpDraggableView);
```

```

Comment: you tried `gravity` or `layout_gravity`?

Comment: i tried gravity
lpDraggableView.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM ;

this will set the FAB to bottom but i cant drag it.

Comment: What is the root layout of the `FrameLayout`?

Comment: CoordinatorLayout is the root layout

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the position by yourself if you want to not use Gravity.

This is better aquired in the onResume method where the layout inflation and measurement already finished.

You may use display width and height if you want to do in onCreate.

If you have a custom view you may place your calculation code in the onMeasure method.

Comment: yup i tried by this but i think the button is goint out of the view.

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels ;
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels ; 
    lpDraggableView.topMargin = dpHeight;
    lpDraggableView.leftMargin = dpWIdth;

Comment: Yes, exactly your post, you just need to subtract the size of the button, but heres a problem, in onCreate its size is 0,0, so you can calculate over 42dp for example.